# Phonegap Authentication facebook in WebView error to open window.openDatabase

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, webview

I have open Web view for authentication Facebook in phone gap
android.

After authentication successful I get error:

> Uncaught Security Error: Failed to execute 'open Database' on 'Window': Access
>   to the Web Database API is denied in this context"

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use this [Facebook Plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) because this plugins open login popup in your application so window object change. so first you install InAppBrowser Phonegap plugin, then refer this [Facebook InAppBrowser Phonegap](https://github.com/caiovaccaro/phonegap.facebook.inappbrowser).

In this example all facebook method you can access and using this example solve this error.

Comment: great it really help me out